# Flutter app crashes after processing payment with Google Pay

Tags: android, flutter, android-pay, flutter-packages

I am attempting to set up payment processing in my Flutter app using the [flutter google pay plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_pay). When processing a payment the Google Pay window appears and I am able to select a card and the payment processes successfully. The Google Pay window then closes and the app crashes with the following trace.

```
2020-01-04 15:44:32.699 8789-8789/? E/.grocery_bulle: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-01-04 15:44:42.205 8789-8789/com.phrasing.grocery_bullet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.phrasing.grocery_bullet, PID: 8789
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=991, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.phrasing.grocery_bullet/com.phrasing.grocery_bullet.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result.success(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result.success(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at snail.app.flutter.google.pay.FlutterGooglePayPlugin.callToDartOnPaymentSuccess(FlutterGooglePayPlugin.java:126)
        at snail.app.flutter.google.pay.FlutterGooglePayPlugin.onActivityResult(FlutterGooglePayPlugin.java:291)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:634)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:367)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:546)
        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:594)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
```

Here is the code

```
class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  CartModel _cartModel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _cartModel = Provider.of<CartModel>(context);
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
              child: _CartContents(),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(height: 10, color: Colors.black),
          _CartTotal(),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _makeStripePayment(context);
              },
              child: Text('Buy', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4),
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _makeStripePayment(BuildContext context) async {
    var environment = 'rest'; // or 'production'

    if (!(await FlutterGooglePay.isAvailable(environment))) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Google pay is not available'),
      ));
    } else {
      PaymentItem pm = PaymentItem(
          stripeToken: 'pk_test_1IV5H8NyhgGYOeK6vYV3Qw8f',
          stripeVersion: "2018-11-08",
          currencyCode: "usd",
          amount: "0.10",
          gateway: 'stripe');

      FlutterGooglePay.makePayment(pm).then((Result result) {
        if (result.status == ResultStatus.SUCCESS) {
          Map<Item, int> cartItems = _cartModel.getCart();
          for (Item item in cartItems.keys) {
            int itemCountRequested = cartItems[item];
            Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
              DocumentSnapshot freshSnap =
                  await transaction.get(item.reference);
              int itemCountAvailable = freshSnap['count'];
              int itemCountSent = itemCountAvailable >= itemCountRequested
                  ? itemCountRequested
                  : itemCountAvailable;
              int itemCountRemaining = itemCountAvailable - itemCountSent;
              await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference, {
                'count': itemCountRemaining,
              });
            });
          }
          _cartModel.resetCart();
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text('Your items are on the way!!')));
        }
      }).catchError((dynamic error) {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(error.toString()),
        ));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so what happened with this? Were you able to get it working? Any tips would be very welcome as I am now trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: Hey @dakini no progress yet :(. This seems to be a place where Google Cloud could use better documentation.